# Makefile foreach compiling themes

Tags: foreach, makefile

I'm currently trying to compile all my themes in one go, but I can't seem to get it to work.

E.g.:

```
THEMES := theme_a theme_b theme_c theme_d
build_themes: 
     $(foreach THEME, $(THEMES), sass web/themes/$(THEME)/scss/style.scss web/themes/$(THEME)/css/style.css)
```

But it just compiles the first theme and not all.

Is there something wrong with my iteration?

**EDIT**
After the suggestion by Renaud Pacalet:

```
RUBY    =$(whereis ruby)
SASSC   = $(RUBY) sass --style compressed

THEMES  := theme_a theme_b theme_c theme_d
SASSDIR = build/scss
CSSDIR  = web/themes/custom-themes
SASS    := $(wildcard $(SASSDIR)/style_*.scss)
CSS     := $(patsubst $(SASSDIR)/style_%.scss, $(CSSDIR)/%/css/style.css, $(SASS))

all: $(CSS)

$(CSSDIR)/%/css/style.css: $(SASSDIR)/style_%.scss
    $(SASSC) $< $@
```

But I still can't seem to get it to work

Comment: _can't seem to get it to work_ is not really helpful. May I suggest that you have a quick look at the [Asking section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) of the help center? Anyway, in what you show the `SCSS` variable is used but not defined.

Comment: Changed `$(SCSS)` to `$(SASS)`yet when I run `all` it says `make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.`. And if I run `$(CSSDIR)/%/css/style.css` it says `make: *** No rule to make target `$(CSSDIR)/%/css/style.css'.  Stop.`

Comment: Oh, I got it. It was no error with `nothing to be done` the files just hadn't any changes so that there was nothing to compile. So it does check for the last modification time. I get it. It works now. Thank you :)

Comment: Except that it does not seem to check included files like mixins or partials.

Comment: _it does not seem to check included files like mixins or partials_: yes, `make` is cool but not black magic. It does not know the syntax and semantics of all existing languages; so, it cannot parse your sources to "understand" them and identify alone all secondary dependencies. I'd love that too, but unfortunately `make` is a real tool from the real world. Note that if you have a scss analyser you can tell `make` how to use it to do what you want. This deserves another question...

Comment: How can I compile them then without verifying them first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make is not yet another scripting language. It is a dependency management utility with building capability. Tell it how to compile any theme:

```
web/themes/%/css/style.css: web/themes/%/scss/style.scss
    sass $< $@
```

**Note that the recipe line (`sass $@ $<`) starts with a tab, not spaces.**

This is a [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules). `$<` and `$@` are two [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) that make will substitute respectively by the first prerequisite of the rule and by its target.

This rule means that any CCS named `web/themes/<something>/css/style.css` depends on the (only) prerequisite `web/themes/<something>/scss/style.scss`. If make is told to build a CSS, it will search for the corresponding SCSS. If it does not find the SCSS, it will raise an error. If it finds it, it will compare the last modification dates of the CSS and SCSS. If the CSS is newer than the SCSS, make will consider that the CSS is up-to-date and it will not do anything. Else it will consider that the CSS is outdated and it will expand the recipe (by substituting `$@` and `$<`) and pass it to the shell.

Next, tell make that you want all your themes to be compiled:

```
THEMES := theme_a theme_b theme_c theme_d
CSS    := $(patsubst %,web/themes/%/css/style.css,$(THEMES))

all: $(CSS)
```

And that's it. Just invoke `make all` to get the work done.

The most important thing to remember here is that, thanks to this structure:

```
target: prerequisite
    recipe
```

make will do much better than a naive script loop: it will re-compile a theme only if the CSS is missing or older than the corresponding SCSS. If invoked with the `-j8` option (`make -j8 all`) it will even parallelize the work by launching up to 8 jobs in parallel.

Bonus: make can also find all your SCSS and compute the list of all buildable CSS:

```
DIR  := web/themes
SCSS := $(wildcard $(DIR)/*/scss/style.scss)
CSS  := $(patsubst $(DIR)/%/scss/style.scss,$(DIR)/%/css/style.css,$(SCSS))

all: $(CSS)

$(DIR)/%/css/style.css: $(DIR)/%/scss/style.scss
    sass $< $@
```

Comment: I can't get it to work. I've edited my original post to let you know where I'm at right now.